# phplint deactivated + phpcs deactivated

Tags: sublimelinter, phplint

I'm trying to make `SublimeLinter` work on my Linux. On Sublime Text console I have this errors:

> SublimeLinter: WARNING: phplint deactivated, cannot locate 'phpl' 
>   SublimeLinter: WARNING: phpcs deactivated, cannot locate 'phpcs'

SublimeLinter's path, I have configured like this:

```
"paths": {
        "linux": ["/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jshint/bin",
            "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/csslint/bin",
            "/usr/bin/php -l", "/opt/lampp/bin"],
        "osx": [],
        "windows": []
    },
```

What is missing?

Comment: Are phpcs and phpl installed?

Comment: I'm not sure! How can I check this?

Comment: Hey bro! I've just figured out that I could install it from the package control. 
Your tip resolved all my troubles! Thank you so much!